# Jinja2 if else comparison with less than operator in python flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to populate a table in my html page. I need to convert a string variable to float and compare it to a threshold value in a jinja2 if statement using Flask.

I am using the below code:

```
{% for index,score in report_card.items() %}
<tr>
    {% if score['english']|float < 90.0 %}
    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><span class="badge badge-danger">{{score['english'] }}</span></td>
    
    {%else%}
    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">{{score['english'] }}</td>
    
    {% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The '<' is registered as part of the html and causes an error in rendering. How to do this comparison properly?

Comment: Have you seen: [If](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if) and [If-expression](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#if-expression)?

Comment: @VladSiv I am a beginner in jinja. I was referring to this documentation.
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#comparisons
Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong in the code?

Comment: Are you sure you are closing the if tag with `endif`?

Comment: don't you get error message when you run it in console?

Comment: There are not erro messages, but the rendering looks incorrect since '<' is identified as html tag. I have an else and endif statement too. Please see the edit with full code @Vlad

Comment: @charlie_boy Answer updated. I used some dummy data and labeled with red color, not sure how your `class="badge badge-danger"` looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Without the rest of the code it's hard to tell what's exactly going wrong, but the `if` should have `endif`.

Example:

```py
{% if score['english']|float < 95.0 %}
    {{ score['english'] }}
{% endif %}
```

- Edit:

Full example using test data:

```py
# flask file
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

report_card = {
    "1": {"english": "12.2"},
    "2": {"english": "94.0"},
    "3": {"english": "78.0"},
    "4": {"english": "23.0"},
    "5": {"english": "99.0"},
}


@app.route("/")
def template_test():
    return render_template("test.html", report_card=report_card)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML file:

```
# test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    {% for index, score in report_card.items() %}
        <tr>
        {% if score['english']|float < 90.0 %}
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                <span style="background-color:red;">{{ score['english'] }}
                </span>
            </td>
        {% else %}
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">{{ score['english'] }}</td>
        {% endif %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this I get:

[image]